# Extracción y combinación de información de diferentes hojas en Google Sheets con Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal para extraer información de diferentes hojas que mantienen 1 sola columna en común, en este caso los RUT de personas (trabajo en una Universidad), el código que estoy utilizando para realizar este trabajo es el siguiente:

```
function combineData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Variable para detectar hoja en uso
  var s1 = sheet.getSheetByName("PRIORIDAD ACADÉMICA MONITOREO"); //Variable que detecta la hoja 1
  var s2 = sheet.getSheetByName("DATOS ESTUDIANTES"); //Variable que detecta la hoja 2
  var combinedSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("AES"); //Variable de la hoja para pegar los datos cruzados
  var data1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues(); //Variable que obtiene los valores de la hoja 1 para extraer
  var data2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues(); //Variable que obtiene los valores de la hoja 2 para extraer
  var combinedData = []; //Variable vacia para depositar los datos extraidos
  var headerRow =[]; //Variable vacia para depositar el nombre de las columnas


  //Variables que se utilizarán para identificar las columnas a cruzar
  var colDeExtraccion_PA = [5,6,7,15];
  var colDeExtraccion_DE = [1,2,4,5,15];


  //Obtenemos los nombres de las columnas de la hoja DE
  for (let m = 0; m < colDeExtraccion_DE.length; m++){
    var colIndex = colDeExtraccion_DE[m];
    headerRow.push(data2[0][colIndex]);
  }


  //Obtenemos los nombres de las columnas de la hoja PA
  for (let p = 0; p < colDeExtraccion_PA.length; p++){
    var colIndex = colDeExtraccion_PA[p];
    headerRow.push(data1[0][colIndex]);
  }


  //Depositamos las columnas en la variable creada
  combinedData.push(headerRow);


  //Ciclo for que realiza la extracción de los datos para depositar en variable vacia combineData
  for (let i = 1; i < data1.length; i++) { //recorre las filas de la primera planilla (prioridad académica monitoreo)
    var rowData = [];
    var id = data1[i][0];
    rowData.push(id);
    
      for (let k = 1; k < data2.length; k++) { //recorre las filas de la segunda planilla (datos estudiantes)
      if (data2[k][0] == id) { //Condición para ver si el RUT coincide con el de la hoja.
        for (let l = 0; l < colDeExtraccion_DE.length; l++) { //Se recorren los datos que coinciden en la condición y me extrae la información de las columnas que se especificaron
          var colIndex = colDeExtraccion_DE[l];
          rowData.push(data2[k][colIndex]);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
      for (let j = 1; j < colDeExtraccion_PA.length; j++) { //IDEM anterior pero la hoja PA
        var colIndex = colDeExtraccion_PA[j];
        rowData.push(data1[i][colIndex]);
      }
    
    combinedData.push(rowData); //Se deposita todas las filas en que se encontró información
  }
  
  //Rango dinámico para hacer coincidir la cantidad de columnas
  var numeroColumnas = colDeExtraccion_DE.length + colDeExtraccion_PA.length
  var targetRange = combinedSheet.getRange(1, 1, combinedData.length, numeroColumnas);
  targetRange.setValues(combinedData);
}
```

El código funciona bien al momento de tomar los 218 RUT de la hoja de Prioridades Académicas y hacer el cruce con la hoja de Datos de Estudiantes en donde tengo 1190 RUT para hacer los cruces respectivos, al momento de definir las columnas que quiero traer de cada tabla para pegarlas en una hoja, este funciona bien con las columnas que le designo en las variables, pero al momento de pegar el nombre de las columnas que estoy extrayendo, estos no coinciden con las columnas que estoy especificando, por ejemplo:
la primera columna que estoy usando para hacer el cruce son los RUT, por lo tanto debería de traer el nombre de la primera columna como RUT, pero al momento de hacerlo, este me trae otro nombre de la columna.

No tengo suficientes conocimientos utilizando Apps Script, por lo que no comprendo como solucionar esto, en un principio una solución que encontré fue definir los nombres de las columnas de manera manual y luego extraer la información según el orden que le di, pero la idea es que sea de manera automatizada, es decir, si quiero traer los datos cruzados de la columna Estado de Matricula que tengo en la Hoja Datos de Estudiantes, este me cruce los RUT que estoy trabajando y luego me traiga el nombre de la columna y me deposite lo que encontró de esos RUT.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Que son los "RUT de personas"? Por favor describe las partes relevantes de tu hoja de cálculo incluyendo datos de configuración como el país (locale). Incluye datos de entrada muestra y el resultado esperado para dichos datos de entrada.

Comment: Disculpa, el RUT es el n° de identificación que tenemos los residentes de Chile, en la hoja de "Datos de Estudiantes" tengo información personal como nombres, ciudad, establecimiento de procedencia, entre otra información personal y en "Piorirdad académica" tengo datos númericos con respecto a sus asignaturas, como la cantidad de asignaturas inscritas, % de rendimiento académico y la prioridad que definimos como institución, el RUT es común en ambas hojas y el código cruza esa información y solo me selecciona lo que coincida para luego pegarlo en la hoja AES según las columnas que escoja.

Comment: Gracias por responder a mi comentario. Recuerda que todos los datos que son relevantes deben ser incluidos en la pregunta y que este es un espacio con usuarios que hablan español que podrían no estar familiarizados con cosas particulares de un país específico.